# Why I can't use some of HEX-colors that include letters in my embed?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I'm trying to use HEX-color with letters (ex. 2c2f33) and it doesn't work, but If I use something as "3447003" it works. So what should I do to make it work?

```
message.channel.send({embed: {
      color: 2c2f33,
      fields: [
        { name: "Gaming Roles:", value: "<:gta:605106790534742057><@&587234726834733056>\n<:r6s:605106790677348372><@&587234959752822824>\n<:Fortnite:605106790580879361><@&587461980172976168>\n<:pubg:605106790690193428><@&587240268068159497>\n<:arma:605109711703900170><@&587238820890804224>\n<:division:605106790673416202><@&587239012909973517>", inline: true}
      ]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. In this case, once the error is noticed, it's easy to see what "doesn't work" means. But in the future, please specify what error you see, if any, the expected results and what you get instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A color field within an embed object in Discord's Javascript API is of the type *integer*, meaning that it will only take a number as a value.  The Hexadecimal number system is of base 16, meaning that the first 16 numbers are represented using 16 different symbols (0-9, A-F).  Because the color field can only take numeric characters and not alphanumeric characters, Hexadecimal doesn't work.  Thus, Discord's API team decided to use the vastly more common *decimal* (base 10) number system, the system we use every day with 10 symbols that are all numeric characters.  This way, the input in your code will only be numbers.

You have two options that I can think of:

1. Convert your colors yourself from Hexadecimal to Decimal, then use the result in your program instead of the hex code.  The math needed to do this by hand is off-topic, but I can link you to [this website](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html) to do it for you.  This option can be somewhat tedious (even if you use a website) because of the copying and pasting.
2. put `0x` before your hex code in the code.  I'm not 100% sure this would work in JS; What it does is it marks the number as being hexadecimal, then converts it to decimal for you.

**Resources:**

https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#DOC_CHANNEL/embed-object

https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal_numeral_system

**Related Tags:**
[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [hexadecimal](/questions/tagged/hexadecimal), [discord.js](/questions/tagged/discord.js)

Comment: *"A color field within an embed object in Discord's Javascript API is of the type* integer *..."* This only applies to *reading* the `color` property; you aren't actually limited to integers in construction.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *string* containing your hexadecimal value.

```js
embed: {
  color: "2c2f33",
  fields: [...]
}
```

When creating a [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed), the `color` property can be set to a [ColorResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ColorResolvable), so it can be any of the following:

- Hex Literal
- **Hex String**
- Number
- RGB Array
- *See hyperlinked documentation page for a list of pre-defined strings.*